# Mathematical rectangle function Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to make convolution of gaussian and rectangular functions like that:

```
from numpy import linspace, sqrt, sin, exp, convolve, abs
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def gauss(x, x0=0, sigma=1):
    return exp(-1*(x-x0)**2/(2*sigma**2))

def rect(x):
    return 1 if abs(x)<=0.5 else 0

x = linspace(-10, 10, 100)

f1 = gauss(x, sigma=1)
f2 = rect(x)
fsum = convolve(f1, f2)

y = linspace(-10, 10, 199)

plt.plot(x, f1)
plt.plot(x, f2)
plt.plot(y, fsum)
plt.show()
```

But I can't correctly describe rect function:

```
return 1 if abs(x)<=0.5 else 0
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: Just go with `(np.abs(x)<=0.5).astype(float)`

Comment: I tried, It didn't help

Comment: By "just", I mean `return (np.abs(x)<=0.5).astype(float)`. No `if`

Comment: What are you expecting the function to return? Youre passing an array of multiple values but returns a single value. Maybe theres some built in numpy method to do it but you could use a list comprehension. `rect = np.array([1 if np.abs(n)<=0.5 else 0 for n in x])`
Edit: Aah, go with @tom's solution..

Comment: Thanks for help!!

Comment: Also have a look at the step function [np.heaviside](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.heaviside.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you want an array of 0 and 1 values, the same shape as `x`, you can use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
In [8]: x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 100)
In [9]: np.where(abs(x)<=0.5, 1, 0)
Out[9]: 
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

So your function could be:

```
from numpy import linspace, sqrt, sin, exp, convolve, abs, where
...
def rect(x):
    return where(abs(x)<=0.5, 1, 0)
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
def rect(x):
    y=x
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if abs(x[i]) <= 0.5:
            y[i] = 1
        else:
            y[i] = 0
    return y
```